# How to avoid circular update:modelValue event on VueJS3 component?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a VueJs component that allows the `v-model="form.title"` parameter:

```
<template>
    <wysiwyg-editor :value="modelValue" @update="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" />
</template>

<script>
import WysiwygEditor from './WysiwygEditor'

export default {
    emits: ['update:modelValue'],
    components: { WysiwygEditor },
    props: {
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: null
        }
    },
    watch: {
        modelValue (to) {
            this.editor.setValue(to)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Problem of that is that whenever the user writes in the input field, the data is `$emit` to the parent, which gets the new value and triggers down the `watch` on the current element, which updates the value back, causing writing issues.

I need to have the `watch` property because the parent can modify the value that needs to be reflected in this component.

I thought about using the `mounted` callback on the component, but the component stays on the page, so it isn't mounted at every change from the parent.

How can I do to avoid a circular call?

Comment: you could add a second parameter `from` to your watcher which will receive the old value.  only call `setValue(to)` if `to !== from` which should break circular calls.

Comment: This assumes the modelValue was set from within the component,but it's not the case. The from has the previous value

Comment: the watcher should fire regardless of if the change was made in the Parent or Child.  If the parent updates the value and you want to ignore it because of some circular back-and-forth where the Child already has the value, then checking `from == to` is how you ignore the update from the Parent.